# Having quite a lot of issues when write massive record to firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

From my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44169412/try-to-understand-how-well-can-denormalize-work-with-firebase-database-in-my-sce) let me decided to write huge amount of data to
firebase databases for testing purpose.

Here is the outcome

- 1000 record: Nothing significant happen it work fine.
- 10000 record: Response from all other read operation from firebase return only after the write operation complete.
- 100000 record : Same as the result of 10000 record but took more longer, I can't perform any firebase operation unless force close the app and reopen it. The screen started hang for some time might because I perform loop in main thread(ios).
- 1 million record : I'm afraid so never try.

The reason I need to write such amount of data is because I building some  social app(android,ios,web) it use SQL before but I think it is time to switch to firebase. By studying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31614653/designing-a-firebase-based-scalable-feed-model) I having the idea on how to build a user feed without using the `IN` clause. The data structure look like this

```
users
  user1
    name: bob
  user2
    name: alice
    follows: 
      user1: true

posts
  post1
     author: user1
     text: 'Hi there'

feeds
  user2
    post1: true
```

As the example If one of the user having 61 million follower it will need to insert record to 61 million `feeds/$uid/`. Which the write operation barely survive with 100k. On this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544325/firebase-data-structure-is-the-firefeed-structure-relevant) it suggest not to do it in the client side but big point of firebase is it is backendless how I suppose to write beside from client side.

So my question is there any efficient way to achieve on how to not get other read operation interupt by this kind of massive write operation? Or there is way better data modeling for this?

I really need help. I really apperciated even just a comment.

Comment: It's a little unclear what the issue actually is. It's understood that writing 1 million records will take 'a while' but the bigger question is *why* are you writing one million records. In the big picture, if one user has 61 million followers, each follower would be observing the feeds node. If that user adds/updates a feed, each observer would receive an event notifying them of that feed - so one add or update is all the client app is sending to Firebase. I think you may want to update your question by clarifying the use case and please include code so we can see what your actually doing.

Comment: @Jay Ok my bad.  Let say difference user have difference follower so their feed will be difference. If some one has 61million follower I need add his post to his follower feed which will be writting 61 million record, so I can just do a query with /feed/userId/postId then join it with the /post/postId. Another alternative option is to listen all the current user following post this might be a problem in read operation if the user follow abount thousand of user.

Comment: I think you may be approaching this backwards. You should have a /feeds node that all users are observing for feeds that contain a certain uid that are interested in. So for example say uid_0 wants to be notified when feeds are posted from uid_5. If uid_5 posts a new feed, they would post it to  /feeds/feed_xx/posted_by: uid_5. Then, uid_0 would then be notified of that feed. No need to do anything more than that. Maybe I am misunderstanding the use case?

Comment: @Jay Like twitter home feed. Twitter feed will having all the person current following account and his own tweet on home feed according to the tweet created date. That why I create all user per feed. Thank for reply anyway.

Comment: If you read what you wrote in your comment, *all the person current following account*. That's exactly what I said; users choose to follow another user - those users have added an observer to the users (feed) they want to follow. When the person being followed posts something to their feed, the followers are sent an event.

Comment: @Jay Sorry I didn't realise I didn't complete the comment yesterday. But let say uid_0 follow 5000 people will it be good if add 5000 listener? Because there is no IN clause like SQL so I had to create separate listener for each /post/followingUID/.  Beside If I update the record by using cloud function did you think will it be good? Really thank you =)))

Comment: No no. If uid_0 wants to follow 5000 people here are two options. 1) Attach a listener to the feeds node. That will notify uid_0 of any new feeds. In code you can ignore the ones you are not interested in and pass through the ones you are. 2) Attach a query to the feeds node for each feed uid_0 is interested in. They will only receive events for those feeds that match the query.

Comment: But how about the initial step? I mean the first time I grab those data from the feed and display it? If there is 100 million post in my node tree I will need to first get 100 million post then filter out which is the uid_0 current follow user then pick the latest 15 post according to the followers. Could you give me an example as answer.

Comment: Sorry for being stupid, I just bump into nosql recently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with an example Firebase structure using observers and events to capture feeds from specific users.

We have a users node which stores data about all of the users, in this case just their name. We also have a feeds node which stores the feeds. In this case we could also call it messages as we are just storing messages users create.

```
users
  uid_0
    name: "Scott"
  uid_1
    name: "Frank"
  uid_2
    name: "Leroy"

feeds
  feed_0
    uid: uid_1
    msg: "some message from uid_1"
  feed_1
    uid: uid_2
    msg: "a message from uid_2"
```

Assume that Scott (uid_0) wants to 'subscribe' to any feeds from Frank and Leroy.

```
func addSomeFeeds() {
    self.addFeed(uidFeed: "uid_1")
    self.addFeed(uidFeed: "uid_2")
}

func addFeed(uidFeed: String) {
    let feedsRef = self.ref.child("feeds")
    let feedQuery = feedsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "uid").queryEqual(toValue: uidFeed)
    feedQuery.observe(.childAdded, with: { snapshot in

        let feedDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
        let msg = feedDict["msg"] as! String
        print(msg)
    }) 
}
```

and the output

```
some message from uid_1
a message from uid_2
```

and then if uid_2 adds another feed (with a message)

```
Feed From uid_2
```

The above code is run on Scott's device and attaches an observer to the Feeds node that 'watches' for any feeds *added* by Frank or Leroy.

This could expanded and watch for changes via .childChanged so if the feed has multiple 'posts' in it any time a post is updated in a particular feed, Scott's app will be notified of the changes within that feed.

Another option is to add a more generic observer to the feeds node wheras the app would be notified for *any* feed added, changed or removed. In that case, when the app receives a snapshot of the feed, simply compare it to an array of feeds the user is interested in and if doesn't match one of those, ignore it, otherwise, notify the user.

Comment: Thx bro i think i can be able to fix my issues by studying ur example. Thx for ur effort

Comment: Just one thing before u leave. If i subscrive thousand of feed will this method work effienciency?

Comment: @teckwei Yes, it's very efficient and fast!